# How can I save notes created by indicator-stickynotes?

Tags: indicator, stickynotes

I discovered [indicator-stickynotes](http://sourcedigit.com/16151-how-to-install-sticky-notes-indicator-in-ubuntu-15-04-ubuntu-14-04-and-ubuntu-14-10/) as a simple to use note tray icon application.

However, I don't yet understand how I can preserve the content of a created note. Each time I close and reopen the application (e.g. after a reboot), all my notes are gone

**Example:**

The content of the note below disappears once I close and reopen it.

[image]

**Video example:**

https://youtu.be/avpnK57gSug

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not meant to work that way

Comment: If you like you can try BasKet Note Pads. It's a feature rich notes application which automatically preserves notes across boots. You don't have to manually save. Albeit, it may be a little heavier than the sticky notes indicator applet, but if you don't mind the slight overhead, definitely worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Indicator-stickynotes` does save your notes on reboot.

Upon reboot, open `sticky notes` using dash.

[image]

After that you will get an icon for sticky notes in top bar. Click on that icon and select `Show All` option and all the sticky notes will appear on screen.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I do. But each time I reopen Indicator Stickynotes, I only see a blank new note. And by the way, why are your notes yellow and mine white? Please see this video for further information: https://youtu.be/avpnK57gSug

Comment: @orschiro: regarding colour scheme, you can change colour of sticky notes by clicking on down arrow icon in sticky notes and selecting `Settings` option and then change colour as you want and could you please post output of `~/.config/indicator-stickynotes` file in your Q.

Comment: Problem almost solved! My config was somehow broken and I deleted it. Now it preserves the content but I still cannot change the background colour. [config](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/12c0431054ad7aac6ba9154d5fd8313b). [gif](http://i.imgur.com/6WvTCJt.gif)

Comment: @orschiro: Try changing RGB  values in `{"bgcolor_hsv": [0.8514492753623188, 0.26589595375722547, 0.6784313725490196]`. I think broken config is causing some problem. You should consider reinstalling sticky notes.

Comment: I changed the config manually but the colour is still not changing. Well, anyway. At least I have my notes now. :-) Thanks for your help. I will stick to the white background. It must be a problem on my system.